# Erlang Web Development (Erlang newbie)

Tags: erlang, n2o

I am creating a web app in Erlang with n2o. My current dilemma is the automatic syncing of changes i make to the app's source code to that with the accommodating release.

For example, I startup my app release in the `erlang` console, go to specific `localhost`:? address and see `index.erl` being reflected in the page with `<span>Hello</span>` shown. I then go back to modify the `index.erl` file to say `Hello World` instead. The changes are not reflected. So i end up regenerating a release to see the new changes.

I guess I could write a bash script to synchronize changes between the app source files and the release libraries, but I imagine there must be better ways of doing this.

What is the appropriate way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synchronization capability you're looking for is explained in the [n2o README](https://github.com/5HT/n2o#developer-scripts-for-sync).

Comment: Thanks Steve. You are correct. 5HT helped me understand how synrc/active (https://github.com/synrc/active) helps with this issue during development.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the git-repo 5HT/n2o and follow the instructions in the samples section of that repository. Make a change to one of the source files and once they are saved, you can see the updated changes in the erlang shell as well the web site itself.